# Understanding UB and pointer-arithmetic

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic, reinterpret-cast

I have a generic reference-counted heap-allocated wrapper class. So my class is basically just a pointer:

```
template <typename T>
class Refcounted {
    struct model { 
        std::atomic<std::size_t> count{1}; 
        T value;
    };
    model* m_self;
public:
    ...
    Refcounted(const Refcounted& other) : m_self(other.m_self) {
        assert(m_self);
        ++m_self->count;
    }
    ...
    T& operator*() { return m_model->value; }
};
```

Now, I'd like to be able to get a `T&` even in a context where `T` is forward-declared. As I understand it, I can't, because if `T` is just forward-declared, it can't know the layout of `model` (in particular, it can't know the offset of `value` because it can't know `T`'s alignment).

I believe that if I swapped the order of `model`, it would be well-defined behavior to `reinterpret_cast`, correct?:

```
template <typename T>
class Refcounted {
    struct model { 
        T value;
        std::atomic<std::size_t> count{1}; 
    };
    model* m_self;
public:
    Refcounted(T&& x) : m_self(new model(std::move(x))) {
        static_assert(offsetof(model, value) == 0, "Using this assumption below to reinterpret_cast");
    }
    ...
    Refcounted(const Refcounted& other) : m_self(other.m_self) {
        assert(m_self);
        ++m_self->count;
    }
    ...
    T& operator*() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_model); }
};
```

Assuming that's correct, great... but now the copy-constructor requires `T` to be defined because it needs to find `m_self->count`. I had a thought for dealing with that, but I suspect it's UB: If I set up the `model` struct so that `std::atomic<std::size_t> count` is first and there's no padding between it and the `T`, then `Refcounted` keeps a `void*` pointer to the `value` field, as in `m_valptr{&(new model(std::move(x)))->value}`, then I could `reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_valptr)` to get at the `value` (which I think (?) is still well-defined-behavior). Is there any defined way to go from that pointer to a pointer to `count`? In principal, it's just decrementing the pointer by `std::atomic<std::size_t>`, but I suspect it breaks rules that I don't fully understand about what can and cannot be done with pointers.

I could add a second pointer to `Refcounted` or I could make `model` use a virtual interface, but that adds overhead. I feel like this should be possible but that there are spooky language rules getting in the way.

Comment: _>"I set up the model struct so that std::atomic<std::size_t> count is first and there's no padding between it and the T"_.  
How?

Comment: The simplest would be to just require that that's the layout (`static_assert(ofsetof(model, value) == sizeof(std::atomic<std::size_t>))`) and accept that if `T` is more-aligned than `std::size_t` it won't be constructible.

Comment: You can just store two pointers in `Refcounted` or use a `char` buffer for both members, aligning `T` always by the maximum non-overaligned alignment, assuming you don't care about the overhead.

Comment: @user17732522 are you saying it would be defined behavior if what I allocate is a `std::array<std::byte, N>` aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, then use placement-`new` to place into it my `T` at a compatible alignment on the "right" and just "left" of it, place my `std::atomic<std::size_t>`? That is, I'd have a `std::byte*` that is where my `T` lives, but it's defined to decrement that pointer by `sizeof(std::atomic<std::size_t>)` since it's within the same buffer of `std::byte`s, then it's still well-defined behavior to `reinterpret_cast` that back to a `std::atomic<std::size_t>*`?

Comment: @Ben Yes, you just need to add `std::launder` after the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Right, so the accesses would look like `return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<std::size_t>*>(midpoint - sizeof(std::atomic<std::size_t>)));` and `return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(midpoint));`, correct? Would I expect the `std::launder` to slow things down at all?